# Programmatically find path to the cpp package irrespective of workspace from within the cpp node

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

Ubuntu 22.04, ROS2 Humble

Hi,

Is there a programmatic way for a ros2 cpp node to resolve the full path of its parent package?

For instance I have a package that contains a cpp node as shown below

```
/home/az/ros2_ws/src/ros2_cpp_package/src/cpp_node.cpp
```

I can find the path to the home directory using `cstdlib` and this command `std::string homeDir = getenv('HOME')` in `cpp_node.cpp`.

However the remaining part `/ros2_ws/src/ros2_cpp_package/`, I had to hardcode which I want to avoid to make my code easily usable by other users when they would download it from my github repo.

Any help and suggestions would be most appreciated.

With best,
Azmyin

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what files you're trying to find, but there are some tools that can help: `get_package_share_directory`!

See example in Nav2 [1]. Any files stored in the shared path of the package can be found (e.g. xml, yaml, anything you `install()`-ed there). There are a few other methods [2] you can use as well to obtain file path locations, so hopefully that should help.

PS: they also exist in python3 as well

[1] https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_bt_navigator/src/navigators/navigate_through_poses.cpp#L60

[2] https://github.com/ament/ament_index/tree/rolling/ament_index_cpp/include/ament_index_cpp

Comment: Thanks for the links. Yea, I should have clarified. The ros2 cpp node in the question above, looks for a number of local files to load some configuration parameters. These files are located in different local directories within the parent package. Hence I wanted to find the parent path in a way that it can be used by any user without requiring them to manually updating the path after downloading my ros2 package.